# Display: table-cell does not lineup

Tags: html, css

Just wondering why the containers here do not line up.
Could anyone help?
Thank you.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpmtz

Comment: I don't see any code...

Comment: Please update the code-pen with relevant code. It just says "Recent post 1". What doesn't line up?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jpmtz

Comment: It still just says "Recent post 1" in the HTML column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
.column { vertical-align: top; }
```

then it will line it up on the top. It won't be lined up on the bottom because they have different heights. If you make the heights the same with the vertical-align: top, it'll all be lined up perfectly.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution. See before I was setting vertical-align to the .widget box instead. Thank you bzupnick!

Answer (score 0):

they do , it is just that you style inside element rather than the one dispalyed as table-cell;

Set vertical-align to column or even background:
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/FCltm

Comment: "Recent posts" should touch the very top of the column though, should it not?

Answer (score 0):

They do, in fact, line up vertically.  Since the headers (h3 compared to h4) are of differently sized fonts, and there is 0 padding or margin, the top edge comes down.

Try changing the "recent posts" box to h1 (from h4), and you'll line up again, and hopefully that will show you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.column { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
```

[Demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ciape)

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because two adjacent cell you are using with  different size of header and your  alignment is center...for second cell make `align:top;`